Thermodynamic diagrams in Hamiltonian mechanics
If we compare the fundamental thermodynamic relation $(1)$ and the Hamilton's principal function $(2)$, than we have two practically identical equations:
$$dU=TdS-pdV \tag1$$
$$dS=pdq-Hdt\tag 2$$
In the first one $S$ is entropy, $p$ is pressure and in the second one $S$ is action, and $p$ and $q$ are canonical coordinates.
Now if we construct similar diagrams in the Hamiltonian formalism to the ones that are known in thermodynamics, namely $p,V$ and $T,S$ we would get $H,t$ and $p,q$ diagrams.

Would it be useful to construct these kind of diagrams in Hamiltonian mechanics? Are they examples of canonical transformations?

More commonly, the mechanical/optical analogy is rather between two position/momentum pairs at different instants in time related by a canonical transformation related by the generating function:
$$
dS = pdq-PdQ
$$
Yes these diagrams are useful. For example a $p=p_0$ curve in the $P,Q$ plane will show you how the wave front evolved where every point started with momentum $p_0$. Similarly, a $q=q_0$ curve in the $P,Q$ plane shows you how the wavefront propagated when it started from position $q_0$. For example, for a harmonic oscillator:
$$
\begin{align}
H &= \frac{p^2}2+\frac{q^2}2 & S &= -\frac1{2\tan t}(q^2-2qQ\cos t+Q^2)
 \\
P &= p\cos t-q\sin t & Q &= p\sin t+q\cos t
\end{align}
$$
For concrete thermodynamic applications, it is more convenient to think in terms of free energy:
$$
dF = -SdT-pdV
$$
You can similarly get catastrophes. Take for example the Van der Waals transition. The isotherms below the critical temperature are multivalued in $V$. This is a typical swallow tail catastrophe of $F$ which you also generically obtain in mechanics as well. Just add a nonlinear term to previous harmonic oscillator (e.g. the Duffing oscillator) and you'll get a similar catastrophe after a half period of a trajectory starting at $q_0$.

Thanks. But what about the equation $dS=pdq-Hdt$ than? If we use Stokes theorem we get two bilinear differential forms $dpdq=dHdt$ from which we can easily obtain Hamilton's canonical equations. If we can derive Hamilton's equations from $(2)$ does that mean $(2)$ is a canonical transformation or does it not work like that?
